# OpenCV: Use GaussianBlur or Sobel Derivatives on QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I hope you could help me.

I' m using QT and try to do a simple detection of edges on a image. But my program crash when i launch

```
cv::GaussianBlur( src, src, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

or

```
cv::Sobel( src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

here is my code:

```
QImage      *image1;    
IplImage    *cv_image1;

image1 = new QImage("./image.png");  // Format is ARGB32
cv_image1 = QImage2IplImage(image1);
cv::Mat src(cv_image1);

cv::imshow(window_name, src); // Work Well
cv::Mat src_gray;
int scale = 1;
int delta = 0;
int ddepth = CV_16S;

cv::GaussianBlur(src, src, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT); //Crash Here
cv::imshow( window_name, src);
```

I think that was a problem of format.
But in another program with QIMAGES in ARGB32 this code work well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution.
That' s weird but when I do:

```
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY );
cv::Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

without the cv::GaussianBlur it works well. I just change the last parameter to cv::BORDER_CONSTANT

Answer (score 2):

Try going with proper QImage to cv::Mat conversion using this functions and you should be fine (I also included a conversion from cv::Mat to QImage):

```
cv::Mat cvmat_from_qimage(const QImage& qimage)
{ 
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(qimage.height(), qimage.width(), CV_8UC4, (uchar*)qimage.bits(), qimage.bytesPerLine()); 
    cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_8UC3 ); 
    int from_to[] = { 0,0,  1,1,  2,2 }; 
    cv::mixChannels( &mat, 1, &mat2, 1, from_to, 3 ); 
    return mat2; 
}

QImage qimage_from_cvmat(const cv::Mat& mat)
{ 
    cv::Mat rgb; 
    cvtColor(mat, rgb, CV_BGR2RGB); 
    return QImage((const unsigned char*)(rgb.data), rgb.cols, rgb.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this method of conversion.
But it didn't fixed my problem.
I will retry to add OpenCV to a clean version of my project.

Comment: What is the exact message you receive when your code crashes?

Comment: Ok, I receive "exited with code -1073741819" in Application Output from QTCreator.